# How to Call javascript function from asp.net code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How to call JavaScript function from ASP.NET code behind?

I have JavaScript function and I am using it in a `listview` with a parameter

I want to use it with another parameter in code behind ?

```
 <a href="ChatBox.aspx?id=<%# Eval("USR_UserID")%> " 
     onclick="openWindow(this.href,'chat<%# Eval("USR_UserID")%>',600,600);
     this.blur();
     return false;"><%# Eval("USR_UserName") %></a>
```

that is the `listview` side. How can I use `openwindow` function in code behind fore specific ID?

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 9):

I would think using `RegisterClientScriptBlock` would be the best solution.

Lets say you have a javascript function, `MyJSFunction()`:

```
function MyJSFunction() {
        ...
}
```

In your event, such as a Button Click, you would inject the following code:

C#:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(System.Web.UI.Page), "MyJSFunction", "MyJSFunction();", true);
```

VB.NET:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, GetType(String), "MyJSFunction", "MyJSFunction();", True)
```

This effectively inserts a call to your JavaScript from the code-behind.

Answer (score 5):

Use `RegisterStartupScript` or `RegisterClientScriptBlock`

Injecting Client-Side Script from an ASP.NET Server Control
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478975.aspx