# Convert Silverlight codebehind to Asp.Net in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

I have to convert this code in Asp.Net C# codebehind

js function in the Silverlight code-behind MainPage.xaml.cs file, using the click event of a button.

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   string DatabaseId = "99999999999999999999";
   string UserName = "user";
   string Password = "pass";

   HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("login", DatabaseId, UserName, Password);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not well experienced on this, but based on answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829186/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-asp-net-code-behind), you can try using [ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478975.aspx) to invoke javascript function from ASP.NET code behind. Something like this  :

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   string DatabaseId = "99999999999999999999";
   string UserName = "user";
   string Password = "pass";

   string script = string.Format("login({0}, {1}, {2});", DatabaseId, UserName, Password);

   ScriptManager
    .RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(System.Web.UI.Page), "login", script, true);
}
```

and another reference, a question on how to invoke script with parameters [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189406/passing-a-parameter-to-a-javascript-function)